# SOLR/Lucene: How would one go about extending the Scorer class s.t. it could then be wrapped in a Solr plugin

Tags: plugins, lucene, solr

The reason I am asking this, is because extending the Similarity class or using query function is not enough for me. I plan to personalize user queries in terms of their preferences with respect to document fields. I need to update the score of the documents after the text based scoring has been computed using these preferences (which would have been cached by the Solr plugin). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write a custom [function query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery), it fits your definition of modifying the calculated score with a custom algorithm.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well, however I not sure about one thing: since I need to score each matching document differently by this function, I am guessing I need to use the \_val\_ hook as the boost value... have you any idea on how does this actually work? is this supported by the LuceneQueryParser?